# How can I write to JSON file, without deleting all the content in it?

Tags: json, python-3.x

```
import json
f = open("filename.json", "w")
data = {"username": "justausername"}
json.dump(data, f)
```

When I run this code, all the data in the "filename.json" is replaced by "{'username': 'justausername'}". Please help!

Comment: Do you want to append the new data to the existing data in the file? And what is already there in the file, and in what way do you want to add the new one to the existing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read the file
2. Parse the JSON to a data structure
3. Modify the data structure instead of creating a new one
4. Serialise the data structure back to JSON
5. Write it to the file

Consider using a real database instead so that you get benefits like automatic protection for concurrent edits. SQLite is a good choice if you want a single file to store the data in.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

with open("filename.json", "r") as f:  # reading a file
    data = json.load(f)  # deserialization

data["username"] = "justausername"  # modifying the python object

with open("filename.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)  # serializing back to the original file
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. You are right, but how can I add a section in the existing JSON file? (Sorry for the broken English)

Comment: what do you mean by adding a section in JSON?

Comment: Like, if the file content is: "{user:["hi"]}"
Add the "password:[ANYTHING IN THERE]"

Comment: Oh, wait... I can just make this: "passwd = ["THIS IS A PASSWORD"]
json.dump(passwd, f)"
hahaha